# Yii random number generator function

Tags: function, random, yii

In yii i am creating random number generating function. I am using function as-

```
public function randomNumber()
{
    //for generating random number
    $length =3;
    $chars = array_merge(range(0,9));
    shuffle($chars);
    $password = implode(array_slice($chars, 0,$length));
    echo $password;

}
```

but in above function its creating random number as per length specified. i.e. if length is defined as 2, then it will create 2 digit number,if 3 then 3 digit number and so on. Now my condition is i want to generate random number between 1 to 1000. It can be 1 digit, 2 digit or 3 digit. So how to modify this function? Or is there any other way? Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$length = rand(1,3);
$chars = array_merge(range(0,9));
shuffle($chars);
$password = implode(array_slice($chars, 0,$length));
echo $password;
?>
```

But, actually, i think you must use it like this :)

```
<?php
$password = rand(1,1000);
echo $password;
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use this function:

```
Yii::app()->getSecurityManager()->generateRandomString($length);
```

Documentation of this function can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#generateRandomString()-detail).

Comment: Awesome sauce!!